# Depth test with point sprite in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, particles

I am trying to do a particle system with OpenGL 3 using point sprite.

I use a VBO with GL_STREAM_DRAW where I put the coordinate of every particle.
During each frame, I update the VBO with the new particle coordinate. The particle are simply rendered with GL_POINTS, using GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE.

I noticed that some particles where overlayed by other despite the fact that they were supposed to be closer to the camera.

The point sprite are actually drawn by order of draw call and not by depth, which create situation like this :

[image: The farthest particle is drawn first, the closes particle is drawn second.]

Here the farthest particle is drawn first, the closes particle is drawn second. As expected, the closet particles completely cover the one behind it.

[image: This time the order is reversed.]

Here, the draw order is reversed resulting in the farthest particle being visible.

I try using OpenGL depth testing using

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glDepthRange(0.f, 1.f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_CLAMP);
```

But it just result in nothing being drawn.

As I understand it, one way to resolve this problem is to reorder the particles by depth but this solution would be very costly on the CPU for many particle so is there a way to have proper depth testing for point sprite on the GPU ?

The vertex shader use for drawing the particle is the following :

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

uniform float time;
uniform mat4 camera;

smooth out float dist;

void main()
{
    vec4 cameraPos = position + vec4(0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    gl_Position = camera * cameraPos;
    dist = sqrt(dot(camera * cameraPos, position));
    gl_PointSize = 15.0/dist;
}
```

The fragment shader :

```
#version 330

out vec4 colour;
uniform float time;

smooth in float dist;

float map(float value, float inMin, float inMax, float outMin, float outMax) {
  return outMin + (outMax - outMin) * (value - inMin) / (inMax - inMin);
}

void main()
{
//  colour = vec4(pos.x, pos.y, 1.0, 1.0);
    if(dot(gl_PointCoord-0.5,gl_PointCoord-0.5)>0.25)
        discard;
    else {
        float g = (dot(gl_PointCoord-0.5,gl_PointCoord-0.5) > 0.22 ? 0.6 : map(dot(gl_PointCoord-0.5,gl_PointCoord-0.5), 0.0, 0.21, 0.0, 0.6));
        colour = vec4(g, g*sin(time)*sin(time)*cos(time), sin(dist), 1.0);
    }
}
```

The full code (minus some boilerplate code):

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/vec4.hpp>
#include <glm/mat4x4.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/trigonometric.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <cmath>

#include "tools.h"
#include "shader.h"
#include "data.h"

#define BENCHMARK 230000
#define MAX_POINT 2
#define TTL 100

void init_program(GLuint* program)
{
    std::vector<GLuint> shaders;
    shaders.push_back(create_shader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, read_file("data/particle.vs")));
    shaders.push_back(create_shader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, read_file("data/particle.fs")));
    *program = create_program(shaders);
    std::for_each(shaders.begin(), shaders.end(), glDeleteShader);
}

bool first=true;
void create_new_point(Point* p) 
{
    // Testing draw order
    if(first)
        p->pos = glm::vec4(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    else
        p->pos = glm::vec4(0.f, 0.f, 0.8, 1.f);

    p->dir = glm::vec4(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    p->ttl = TTL+(TTL*(distrib(gen)/2.0));
    first = false;
}

void update_point(Point* p, double dt)
{
    if((p->ttl - dt) <= 0)
        create_new_point(p);
    else
    {
        glm::vec4 speed(dt/2.0);
        p->pos += (p->dir*speed);
        p->ttl = p->ttl - dt;
    }
}

void vbo_point(std::vector<Point>& points, float* data, GLuint* vbo, bool update)
{
    for(size_t n=0; n<points.size(); ++n)
    {
        if(update)
        {
            data[n*4] = points[n].pos.x;
            data[n*4+1] = points[n].pos.y;
            data[n*4+2] = points[n].pos.z;
            data[n*4+3] = points[n].pos.w;
        }
        else
        {
            data[n*4] = 0;
            data[n*4+1] = 0;
            data[n*4+2] = 0;
            data[n*4+3] = 0;
        }
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *vbo);
    if(update)
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(float)*4*points.size(), data);
    else
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*4*points.size(), data, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

int main(void)
{   
    GLFWwindow* window;
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 768, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress);

    // Init data
    GLuint vbo, vao, program;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    init_program(&program);

    // VAO
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glEnable(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);

    /*
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
        glDepthRange(0.f, 1.f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_CLAMP);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND) ;
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    */

    // Time data
    double prev = 0.0;
    double curr = 0.0;
    double frameTime = 0.0;

    // Init Points
    std::vector<Point> points;
    for(size_t n=0; n<MAX_POINT; ++n)
    {
        Point tmp = {glm::vec4(0), glm::vec4(0), 0};
        points.push_back(tmp);
    }
    float* data = new float[4*points.size()];
    for(size_t n=0; n<points.size(); ++n)
        update_point(&points[n], 0);
    vbo_point(points, data, &vbo, false);

    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    GLint time = glGetUniformLocation(program, "time");
    GLint camera_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "camera");
    glm::mat4 camera_matrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.f), 1.33f, 0.1f, 10.f);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        curr = glfwGetTime();
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 0.f);

        glUseProgram(program);
        glUniform1f(time, glfwGetTime());
        glUniformMatrix4fv(camera_location, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(camera_matrix));

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, points.size());
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glUseProgram(0);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();

        for(size_t n=0; n<points.size(); ++n)
            update_point(&points[n], frameTime);
        vbo_point(points, data, &vbo, true);

        std::cout << std::fixed;
        std::cout.precision(8);
        std::cout << "\rfps: " << 1.f/frameTime << " | Point drawed :" << points.size()
            << " | TTL1: " << points[0].ttl;

        prev = glfwGetTime();
        frameTime = prev-curr;
    }

    delete[] data;

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I press tab+enter by mistake before posting the full question. You can see the update now.

Comment: How are you drawing? How is your matrix set up? Any shaders? Or are you using the fixed function pipeline?

Comment: @IvanRubinson I am just doing glDrawArrays with GL_POINTS on a VBO containing the coordinate of each particles. There is no matrix aside from the perspective matrix generated using GLM. The shaders are posted on the question.

Comment: @Maeln: We still need to see what matrices you're using, as well as the vertex data and so forth.

Comment: @NicolBolas The full code can be seen on pastebin https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8960522

Comment: You never clear your depth buffer.

Comment: @derhass Clearing the depth buffer seems to help. I can now use GL_DEPTH_TEST and it fix the issue with the two particle example. But when I use more particle, I still have some weird overlap : [Image](http://i.imgur.com/kAF2XwR.png) (With the shader, the closest particle are bigger).
The new code : [pastebin](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8960917).

Comment: I think my vertex shader is actually buggy. The point size is calculated using  the distance between the particle and the camera like this `dist = sqrt(dot(camera * cameraPos, position));` but I think the real distance is actually : `dist = sqrt(dot(cameraPos, position));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually tied to 2 issue :

1 - The Depth Buffer was never cleared as user [derhass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551082/depth-test-with-point-sprite-in-opengl?noredirect=1#comment70318887_41551082) mentionned in the comment.

2 - The point size in the vertex buffer was computed in the wrong way. The perspective matrix was applied only to the camera position and not to the vertex position. It should be `dist = distance(cameraPos, position));` instead of `dist = sqrt(dot(camera * cameraPos, position));`